# MySQL - How do I update the decimal column to allow more digits after dot

Tags: mysql

I have this `decimal(20,2)` column in MySQL tables:

```
no  
-----
10.01
10.09
10.10
10.11
10.19
10.99
```

What is the easiest way to update that decimal value to

```
no
-------
10.001
10.009
10.010
10.011
10.099
..
10.100
10.101
```

If I only change column to `decimal(20,3)`, I have 10.010, 10.020 ... 10.990

Comment: what you want please explain ?

Comment: Changing field type should not change the value by itself, and mysql is behaving just like it should. You have to manually update the values to achieve what you want.

Comment: Check my answer below. Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

That should work:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET no = no DIV 1 + MOD(no, 1) / 10
```

The two following functions do the following:

```
no DIV 1 => 10.019 DIV 1 = 10
MOD(no, 1) => MOD(10.019, 1) = 0.019
```

Comment: Maybe a temporary column is needed to hold this value (`decimal(20,3)`)

Comment: After change type to decimal(20,3) and run `UPDATE TableName
SET no = no DIV ...` i have error "Duplicate entry '509.010'. Collumn data after change format and before run UPDATE: `509.010
509.020
509.030
509.040
509.050
509.060
509.070
509.080
509.090
509.100
509.110
509.120`

Comment: You did not mention at all that this number must be unique!